# hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, timezone

Using set up as

- Spring framework 5.0.2.RELEASE
- Spring Security 5.0.0.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.11.Final

I followed [spring boot](https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/) & [Vlad's link](http://in.relation.to/2016/09/12/jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property/) to configure my application as below

**db.properties -**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/appname?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
jdbc.username = xxx
jdbc.password = xxx
jdbc.minPoolSize = 5
jdbc.maxPoolSize = 20
jdbc.maxIdleTime = 30000
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="in.greenstack.ikon")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/resources/db.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "myDataSource")
    ....

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "in.greenstack.ikon.entity" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", 
                environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
        return properties;        
   }
```

**Entity -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT_MASTER")
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "START_DATE")
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "END_DATE")
private Date endDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FINANCIAL_YEAR")
private FinancialYear financialYear;
```

**Table Definition -**

```
    CREATE TABLE `PROJECT_MASTER` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FINANCIAL_YEAR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `START_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `END_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
```

**Logs -**

```
    2018-06-13 16:39:03 DEBUG SQL:92 - insert into PROJECT_MASTER (ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_ID, CONVERSION_METHOD_ID, CURRENCY_ID, DESCRIPTION, END_DATE, FINANCIAL_YEAR, HIERARCHY_ID, IMPORT_FROM_PREVIOUS, NAME, OPENING_PROJECT_ID, START_DATE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into PROJECT_MASTER (ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_ID, CONVERSION_METHOD_ID, CURRENCY_ID, DESCRIPTION, END_DATE, FINANCIAL_YEAR, HIERARCHY_ID, IMPORT_FROM_PREVIOUS, NAME, OPENING_PROJECT_ID, START_DATE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:55 - Registering statement [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement@747dab [wrapping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement@1abace9: insert into PROJECT_MASTER (ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_ID, CONVERSION_METHOD_ID, CURRENCY_ID, DESCRIPTION, END_DATE, FINANCIAL_YEAR, HIERARCHY_ID, IMPORT_FROM_PREVIOUS, NAME, OPENING_PROJECT_ID, START_DATE) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2709 - Dehydrating entity: [in.greenstack.ikon.entity.Project#<null>]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE IdentifierValue:130 - ID unsaved-value: 0
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE IdentifierValue:130 - ID unsaved-value: 0
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [TestTimeZone1 FY2017-2018 IGAAP]
**2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [5] as [DATE] - [2018-03-31]**
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE IdentifierValue:130 - ID unsaved-value: 0
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [30]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [8] as [BOOLEAN] - [null]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [TestTimeZone1]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [null]
**2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [11] as [DATE] - [2017-04-01]**
2018-06-13 16:39:03 DEBUG IdentifierGeneratorHelper:78 - Natively generated identity: 63
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:91 - Releasing result set [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@182014e [wrapping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@d243c6]]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 DEBUG ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:104 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:132 - Closing result set [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@182014e [wrapping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@d243c6]]
2018-06-13 16:39:03 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:68 - Releasing statement [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement@747dab [wrapping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement@1abace9: **insert into PROJECT_MASTER (ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_ID, CONVERSION_METHOD_ID, CURRENCY_ID, DESCRIPTION, END_DATE, FINANCIAL_YEAR, HIERARCHY_ID, IMPORT_FROM_PREVIOUS, NAME, OPENING_PROJECT_ID, START_DATE) values (1, null, 2, 'TestTimeZone1 FY2017-2018 IGAAP', '2018-03-30', 2, 30, null, 'TestTimeZone1', null, '2017-03-31')]]**
```

As can be seen from above logs, that the binding parameter is the correct value (1st April 2017 & 31st March 2018) sent from client, but when saving in db it is still saving incorrect dates.

Kindly advice what I have missed.

**pom.xml -**

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.11</mysql.connector.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this(it worked for me). Write below code snippet in your spring boot main application file.

```
@PostConstruct
public void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

[Source](https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/)

Comment: That's a different approach! Setting the JVM's default timezone will influence so much more than Hibernate - including undesired side effects. If you want to avoid these OR if you want Hibernate to work with a different time zone than your JVM's, you have to use `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone`. And that's what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should put `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC` in `application.yml`/`application.properties` of `main/` or `test/`, not in `db.properties`. And, I think `.properties` takes precedence over `.yml`. Correct me if I am wrong.

And, this timezone config is also affected by `Timezone.getDefault()`.

See this post: https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-time-zone-configuration-using-hibernate/

And, as I test, I see that if you want to save a `java.util.Date`, which has no timezone info in itself(only in its `Calendar` property, this is true), and the column definition hold no place for timezone info, this property will affect the value saved to DB, but **not** that when you retrieve the row from DB; the latter is affected only by `Timezone.getDefault()`. Meanwhile, if you set `Timezone.getDefault()`, the **saved** and **retrieved** value will both be the timezone you want.

So, this property may not be the most proper way to manipulate the value of Date, if you **save** and **query** for the information in the same application. Just use `Timezone.setDefault(Timezone.getTimezone("XXX"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", 
                environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
```

to this:

```
 properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
```

Comment: If you run [this test case on my book GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/time/UTCTimeZoneMySQLTimestampTest.java), you'll see how the time_zone setting works and you can do a comparative debug with your code and see why mine works and yours does not.

Comment: I upgraded the hibernate version to 5.2.17.Final as per your project. When I run the changes on my local mysql db which is on India Standard Time, the dates are set correctly. But when I run it on the prod db which is on UTC, the dates are not set correctly. In logs the difference is in the release statement from hibernate. Any clue?

Comment: Updated the post with my pom.xml

Comment: ok got it working finally, I set the serverTimezone=IST in my jdbc url aand now it looks great!

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: serverTimezone=IST didn't work for me so i tried with this in my spring application and it worked:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = GMT+05:30